# Make background jobs available in parent shell

Tags: bash, process, job-control

Sometimes I start several processes by using another script (in my case Ruby). I call this script from a terminal running bash. I would like to start those processes in the script in the background (by using `&`). Unfortunately those processes are not listed when calling `jobs` from within the terminal that run the script. I guess because those are run in a sub shell. This makes it hard to manage them.

Is there a way so that those processes are available by using jobs in the parent shell?

Comment: I wonder if `ptree $$` would show you ruby's jobs from the parent shell.

Comment: ptree does not seem to be available on my system. Ubuntu recommends me to install adacontrol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is for the jobs themselves to be started in the parent shell.

At the moment you have:

> shell -> ruby -> shell -> command

If you could have the commands in a shell script, and not ruby, you could execute that shell script in the current shell with

```
$ source myfile.sh
```

or short-hand:

```
$ . myfile.sh
```

Then any programs started in the background in that script should be in jobs in the current shell.

Comment: Bye bye ruby ... hello bash programming ... brrrrrr ;-)